# SELECT other if value is no

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

I have a column called `is_thumbnail` with a default value of `no`. I select a row based off of `is_thumbnail = 'yes'`

```
    $query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM project_data 
                            WHERE project_id = :projectId 
                            AND is_thumbnail = 'yes' 
                            LIMIT 1");
```

There is a chance that no rows will have a value of `yes`. In that case, I want to select the first row with that same `projectId` regardless of the value of `is_thumbnail`

Now I know I can see what the query returns and then run another query. I was wondering if it was possible to do this in a single query or is there somehow I can take advantage of PDO? I just started using PDO. Thanks!

Example data:

```
id  project_id image                              is_thumbnail 
20  2          50f5c7b5b8566_20120803_185833.jpg  no
19  2          50f5c7b2767d1_4link 048.jpg        no
18  2          50f5c7af2fb22_4link 047.jpg        no
```

Comment: you could order by `is_thumbnail`

Comment: I am only returning one row though. If no rows contain a `is_thumbnail = 'yes'` then I get 0 rows returned

Comment: If I remove WHERE, then I will get images from the wrong project id

Comment: ok I understand using the ORDER BY now, thanks @BevynQ

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$query = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM project_data 
                            WHERE project_id = :projectId 
                            ORDER BY is_thumbnail ASC LIMIT 1");
```

Comment: +1: Once I got my head round the question, you'd already come up with the answer. But wouldn't it just be simpler to create the thumbnails in the first place, Ronnie?

Comment: this seems to be ignoring the fact that is_thumbnail is yes. I changed it to ASC instead of DESC and now it is working, thank you

Comment: @symcbean All of them are thumbnails, the row states that its the thumbnail preview for the whole project if ya know what I mean. I guess the row should be something like, `is_preview`

Comment: just to clarify, its `ASC` not `DESC`

Comment: okay, I must've misunderstood your question slightly, I'll change it to ASC.

Comment: This answer is okay, but I would suggest a slight variation: `ORDER BY is_thumbnail = 'yes' DESC, id DESC LIMIT 1`

Answer (score 1):

Given that the schema described in the question shows multiple rows for a given `project_id`, using only `ORDER BY is_thumbnail ...` solutions may not yield good performance, if there is for instance a single project with many related rows. The cost of sorting rows can potentially be fairly high, and it won't be able to use an index. An alternate solution which may be necessary is:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT *
  FROM project_data 
  WHERE project_id = :projectId AND is_thumbnail = "yes"
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1

  UNION

  SELECT *
  FROM project_data 
  WHERE project_id = :projectId AND is_thumbnail = "no"
  ORDER BY id DESC
  LIMIT 1
) AS t 
ORDER BY t.is_thumbnail = "yes" DESC
LIMIT 1
```

While this solution is a bit more complex to understand, it is able to use a compound index on `(project_id, is_thumbnail, id)` to quickly find exactly one row matching the requested conditions. The outer select ensures a stable ordering of the yes/no rows if both are found.

Note that you could also just issue two queries, and probably get similar or better performance. In order to use the above `UNION` and sub-select, MySQL will require temporary tables, which aren't great in busy environments.